# │ Error running command 'powershell -file ./main.ps1': exec: "PowerShell": │ executable file not found in $PATH. Output:

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, azure-pipelines, devops, terraform-provider-azure

I'm implementing terraform though azure devops pipeline. But need few configurations thorugh Powershell script. For that I've write this null resource and privisioner:

```
       resource "null_resource" "terraform-script" {
          provisioner "local-exec" {
               command = "powershell -file ./main.ps1"
               interpreter = ["PowerShell", "-Command"]
           }
           depends_on = [
             azurerm_resource_group.rg, azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.kc
           ]
       }
```

Both the main.tf and other tf files are in the same directory in which I have my powershell script main.ps1.
But I receive the error that my Path is not correct.
I want to know what i'm doing wrong and how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the provisioner block you've shown in your question is using powershell to run powershell, by constructing a command line like this:

```
PowerShell -Command "powershell -file ./main.ps1"
```

Since your script is already in a separate file, I think it would be more straightforward to execute it directly using `-File` instead of `-Command`, like this:

```
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "./main.ps1"
    interpreter = ["PowerShell", "-File"]
  }
```

The above would run something like the following command:

```
PowerShell -File "./main.ps1"
```

That should work as long as `main.ps1` is in your current working directory, but if you are including your PowerShell script as a file in the same directory as your Terraform module then you'll need to specify the path relative to the module directory instead, like this:

```
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "${path.module}/main.ps1"
    interpreter = ["PowerShell", "-File"]
  }
```

`path.module` is a Terraform expression that returns the relative path from the current working directory to the directory containing the file that this `provisioner` block is written in.

Comment: Hey @Martin Thanks for answer, But it didnt worked out and throw the same error.
I've use this code:

Comment: provisioner "local-exec" {
      command = "./main.ps1"
      interpreter = ["PowerShell", "-File"]
    }

Comment: Hi! Since you didn't show the original error in full in your question, I'm not sure how to improve my answer. Could you edit your original question to now show the updated configuration you tried (based on my answer here) and the entire, exact error Terraform printed out when you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer of my own question,
Here's the solution:

```
 resource "null_resource" "testing-script3" {
        provisioner "local-exec" {
          command     = ".'${path.module}\\main.ps1' "
          interpreter = ["pwsh", "-Command"]
        }
        depends_on = [ azurerm_resource_group.rg,           azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.kc]
      }
```